# Why is EVERYTHING an instance of Class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I don't quite get some things about the Ruby object model. First, is EVERYTHING in Ruby an instance of `Class`? These all produce true:

```
p Object.instance_of?(Class)
p Class.instance_of?(Class)
p Module.instance_of?(Class)
p BasicObject.instance_of?(Class)
class Hello; end
p Hello.instance_of?(Class)
```

I can't quite get how is it possible, if `Object` is a superclass of `Class`, how can it be both a superclass of `Class` and an instance of it at the same time (most diagrams on the Ruby Object Model clearly state this hierarchy)? Which allows for some crazyness like this:

```
p BasicObject.is_a?(Object) #=> true
```

where `BasicObject.class` is `Class`, and `Class.is_a?(Object)`.

By the way, using Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> First, is EVERYTHING in Ruby an instance of `Class`?

No, not everything is an instance of `Class`. Only classes are instances of `Class`.

There are lots of things which aren't instances of `Class`: strings, for example, are instances of `String`, not `Class`. Arrays are instances of `Array`, integers are instances of `Integer`, floats are instances of `Float`, `true` is an instance of `TrueClass`, `false` is an instance of `FalseClass`, `nil` is an instance of `NilClass`, and so on.

Every class is an instance of `Class`, just like every string is an instance of `String`.

> if `Object` is a superclass of `Class`, how can it be both a superclass of `Class` and an instance of it at the same time (most diagrams on the Ruby Object Model clearly state this hierarchy)?

Magic.

Just like in most other languages, there are some core entities that are simply assumed to exist. They fall from the sky, materialize out of thin air, magically appear.

In Ruby, some of those magic things are:

- `Object` doesn't have a superclass, but you cannot define a class with no superclass, the implicit direct superclass is always `Object`. [Note: there may be implementation-defined superclasses of `Object`, but eventually, there will be one which doesn't have a superclass.]
- `Object` is an instance of `Class`, which is a subclass of `Object` (which means that indirectly `Object` is an instance of `Object` itself)
- `Class` is a subclass of `Module`, which is an instance of `Class`
- `Class` is an instance of `Class`

None of these things can be explained in Ruby.

`BasicObject`, `Object`, `Module` and `Class` all need to spring into existence at the same time because they have circular dependencies.

Just because this relationship cannot be expressed in Ruby code, doesn't mean the Ruby Language Specification can't say it has to be so. It's up to the implementor to figure out a way to do this. After all, the Ruby implementation has a level of access to the objects that you as a programmer don't have.

For example, the Ruby implementation could first create `BasicObject`, setting both its `superclass` pointer and its `class` pointer to `null`.

Then, it creates `Object`, setting its `superclass` pointer to `BasicObject` and its `class` pointer to `null`.

Next, it creates `Module`, setting its `superclass` pointer to `Object` and its `class` pointer to `null`.

Lastly, it creates `Class`, setting its `superclass` pointer to `Module` and its `class` pointer to `null`.

Now, we can overwrite `BasicObject`'s, `Object`'s, `Module`'s, and `Class`'s `class` pointer to point to `Class`, and we're done.

This is easy to do from outside the system, it just looks weird from the inside.

Answer (score 2):

You should notice that:

```
p BasicObject.instance_of?(BasicObject)
```

prints `false`.

That is, the expression `BasicObject` is not an instance of `BasicObject`, it is an instance of something else, that is, it is a `Class` object, which represents an object that holds (for example) the class methods, such as `new`.

For example:

```
p (BasicObject.new()).instance_of?(BasicObject)
```

prints `true`, and

```
p (BasicObject.new()).instance_of?(Class)
```

prints `false`.

Answer (score 0):

All of your examples were by definition classes.  Classes are also objects.   But what you didn't do was look at an instance of a class:

```
p Object.new.class
p Hello.new.class
```

Classes define the form of an object, and by definition, a class is a Class.  But when you instantiate class into an object, the object is the new type.  But you can still see that the object's class is itself Class:

```
p Hello.new.class.class
```

Comment: Your last sentence should probably be "… that the object's class's class is itself `Class`" or "… that the object's class is itself a(n instance of) `Class`"